# JavaScript calculate function

Tags: javascript, dom-events

This JS program should return function `ggt(x,z)`. I tried to implement it this way, everything is ok except this part I believe:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=ggt(x,z);
```

What should be added to make this function work properly?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">   
    function calculate(){
        var a=document.getElementById("in1").value;
        var b=document.getElementById("in2").value;
        if(isNaN(a) || isNaN(b)){
          alert("Not a number");
        }else{
          ggt(a,b);
        }
    }
         
    function ggt(x,y){
        if (y==0){
            return x;
        }else{
            var z=x%y; 
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=ggt(x,z);
            return ggt(x,z);
        }
    }
</script> 
<div>
<input id="in1" type="text" />
<input id="in2" type="text" />
<input type="button" onclick="calculate()" value="compute" />

<p id="demo"></p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does "work properly" mean?  What does it do that you don't expect, or not do that you do expect?

Comment: Your current ggt recursion can do 2 things: return x, or not terminate at all. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I always get 0 as result, I am expecting function that includes variable x and  modulus of the calculation those 2 numbers from input

Comment: This function is calling ggt(x,y) recursively until x%y == 0 and then returns x which makes no sense to me since x is never modified, you could simply return x?

Comment: becouse I need modulus also

Comment: Where do you need the modulo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function calculate()

{
  var a = document.getElementById("in1").value;
  var b = document.getElementById("in2").value;

  if (isNaN(a) || isNaN(b)) {
    alert("Not a number");
  } else {

    var values = ggt(a, b);
    
    console.log(values);

    if (values.valid) {
      document.getElementById("demonumber").innerHTML = values.number;
      document.getElementById("demomodulus").innerHTML = values.modulo;
    }
  }
}

function ggt(x, y) {
  var res = {};

  if (y == 0) {
    res.valid = false;
  } else {
    res.valid = true;
    res.number = x;
    res.modulo = x % y;
  }

  return res
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input id="in1" type="text" />
  <input id="in2" type="text" />
  <input type="button" onclick="calculate()" value="compute" />

  <p id="demonumber"></p>
  <p id="demomodulus"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: it should be called via function ggt(x,z) similar to my example.. but ok, tnx

Comment: ok, here is the task, can you please check it?
Function "calculate" without input parameters:
Read the input 1 and store value in variable a,
Read the input 2 and store value in variable b,
If a or b isNaN error in alert box, Otherwise call function "ggt" with parameters a and b: Function "ggt" reads parameters x and y:
If y is 0,  function returns x .Variable z gets the value of x modulo y.
Otherwise, again calling function "ggt" with parameters x and z